# How to get the default content slot sent to a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the following example, I would like a component that doubles a number. This number is passed not as a property, but as content. How is it possible to get the content value in Vue?

```js
var twice = {
  template: '<div>{{ value }}</div>',
  computed: {
     value() {
        return parseInt(this.$slot) * 2;
     }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    twice: twice
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <twice>21</twice>
</div>
```

Comment: Using slots like this is a bad idea. Use props instead...

Comment: @MichalLevý I just realized that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the default slot text by `this.$slots.default[0].text` :

```js
var twice = {
  template: `<div>
     number : <slot></slot><br>
    <div>double : {{ value }}</div>
  </div>`,
  computed: {
    value() {
      return parseInt(this.$slots.default[0].text) * 2;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$slots.default[0].text)
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    twice: twice
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <twice>21</twice>
</div>
```